# Generate Access Token for Facebook

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to the Facebook API. What I am trying to do without success is from my laptop create a new access token for myself through the Facebook API.

Below is the URL I am using to create this new access token:

```
String url = "
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=##########&client_secret=##########&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fintelligentretrieval.com"
```

When I use my client id and then the client_secret (I assume this is the client password) then I get an error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

What exactly is the problem with this and the reason for the error?

Facebook requires a redirect_uri so I decided to dot it to my company site home page.(I figure this isn't the best place to redirect it but where should I redirect this?)

I want to redirect the result (generated access token) to my laptop from where I am making this URL request.

- What exactly is the problem with this?
- Is this possible with a browser like Chrome?
- Is this possible using java?
- Also is it possible to extend the access token expiration to 60 days with this url?

Please let me know if there is any confusion with any part of this post or if the answer can be found elsewhere.

Comment: use `locahost` instead

Comment: Are you sure `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize` is the correct endpoint for getting the `access token`? [Facebook's docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0) advise that you use `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth`

Comment: This is good. However I can't seem to get the actual token now. I just get something back that is blank. I have this url https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=###&client_secret=###&redirect_uri=localhost&response_type=token. I am looking at the api now but can't seem to understand why its not coming back as a json object in the browser. Any thoughts?